# Why some questions in my flagging history are higlighted?

Tags: support, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the colors on Stack Overflow mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean)

I used to flag in stackoverflow and the list can be tracked in "Flagging Summary" page. In that, some posts are seen highlighted. Why do some questions are highlighted? Below is a screen shot of the same.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posts with purple highlighting are posts that have since been deleted.
Ones without are still live.